# Reposition ui elements in unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, layout, panel

I have a question regarding an issue.
How can i make items reposition themselves when I hide or show marked panel?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlZPO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad as there are numerous ways to achieve that:

1. You can use [some of the UI components responsible for auto-layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-UIAutoLayout.html)
2. You can script your components to do what you want
3. You can combine both of the above

In your case the most straightforward solution would probably be to design your UI with [Horizontal](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html) and [Vertical](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html) Layout Groups (or perhaps a [Grid](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html)).

I'm also assuming that by 'hiding' you mean setting the object to inactive. If you're just changing transparency of a canvas group for example, you'd have to resort to numbers 2 & 3.

Unity documentation has some [HowTos](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIHowTos.html) that refer to responsive design.